# Having problems handling multiple custom UITableViewCells using registerNib

Tags: ios, uitableview

In `viewDidLoad` I have:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TypeOneCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
               forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellOne"];
```

and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
TypeOneCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellOne"];
return cell;
```

I want to use the same `UITableViewController` class for all the tables I push/pop. So I'll probably create an enumerated type and a variable for it. So then I'd check which type the view controller is and then make my adjustments accordingly. My question is how I would go about doing this in the same way as above. Is it a matter of (`viewDidLoad`):

```
switch (self.theControllerType) {
         case CPTypeOne:
             [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TypeOneCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                   forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellOne"];
             break;
         case CPTypeTwo:
             [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TypeTwoCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                     forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellTwo"];
             break;
         default:
             break;
}
```

and then (`cellForRowAtIndexPath`):

```
switch (self.theControllerType) {
    case CPTypeOne {
        TypeOneCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellOne"];
        return cell;
        break;
    case CPTypeTwo {
        TypeOneCell *cell;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellTwo"];
        return cell;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Or is this the wrong approach? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the switch condition in the `viewDidLoad` method and everything will work fine.